# javafx.fxml.LoadException: Invalid property

Tags: java, javafx

Couldn't figure out what could be the possible problem??!! Application build is successful and also running successfully, but when i am trying to load the **fxml** file in the JavaFX Scene Builder its not opening and giving the following error:

```
com.oracle.javafx.authoring.persist.FXMLDocument$FxmlParseException: Failed to load FXML file
    at com.oracle.javafx.authoring.persist.FXMLDocument.makeParseException(FXMLDocument.java:400)
    at com.oracle.javafx.authoring.persist.FXMLDocument.load(FXMLDocument.java:311)
    at com.oracle.javafx.authoring.persist.FXMLDocument.checkLayout(FXMLDocument.java:239)
    at com.oracle.javafx.authoring.persist.FXMLDocument.checkLayout(FXMLDocument.java:224)
    at com.oracle.javafx.authoring.Project.forFxml(Project.java:835)
    at com.oracle.javafx.authoring.Project.forFxml(Project.java:807)
    at com.oracle.javafx.authoring.DesignerTool.loadFXMLLayout(DesignerTool.java:197)
    at com.oracle.javafx.authoring.DesignerTool.loadFXMLLayout(DesignerTool.java:185)
    at com.oracle.javafx.authoring.DesignerTool.commonInit(DesignerTool.java:513)
    at com.oracle.javafx.authoring.DesignerTool.initFromRemote(DesignerTool.java:436)
    at com.oracle.javafx.authoring.mbeans.SceneBuilderMgt$1.run(SceneBuilderMgt.java:31)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:76)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:17)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:67)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Invalid property.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$PropertyElement.<init>(FXMLLoader.java:1163)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.createElement(FXMLLoader.java:2372)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2345)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2164)
    at com.oracle.javafx.authoring.persist.FXMLDocument$2.call(FXMLDocument.java:301)
    at com.oracle.javafx.authoring.util.Utils.withFXMLDefaultClassLoader(Utils.java:2216)
    at com.oracle.javafx.authoring.persist.FXMLDocument.load(FXMLDocument.java:298)
    ... 18 mor
```

And my **fxml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="root" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="640.0" prefWidth="960.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.workspaceit.pos.view.HomeViewController">
   <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@themes/theme0/style.css" />
    </stylesheets>
    <children>
      <AnchorPane fx:id="loginPane" prefHeight="598.0" prefWidth="440.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <TextField layoutX="40.0" layoutY="278.0" prefHeight="37.0" prefWidth="358.0" text="devadmin" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="40.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="40.0" />
            <Label layoutX="40.0" layoutY="261.0" text="User name" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="40.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="40.0">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
               </font></Label>
            <Button defaultButton="true" layoutX="40.0" layoutY="399.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleLoginButtonAction" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="77.0" text="Login" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="40.0">
                <graphic>
                  <ImageView fitHeight="14.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@themes/theme0/login.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </graphic>
            </Button>
            <Label layoutX="40.0" layoutY="324.0" text="Password" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="40.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="40.0">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
               </font></Label>
            <PasswordField layoutX="40.0" layoutY="340.0" prefHeight="37.0" prefWidth="358.0" text="dev" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="40.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="40.0" />
            <Hyperlink layoutX="40.0" layoutY="433.0" text="Forgot Password?" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="40.0" />
            <ImageView fitHeight="122.0" fitWidth="172.0" layoutX="38.0" layoutY="190.0" preserveRatio="true" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="38.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="190.0">
               <viewport>
                  <Rectangle2D />
               </viewport>
               <image>
                  <Image url="@themes/theme0/logo.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <ImageView fitHeight="122.0" fitWidth="196.0" layoutX="49.0" layoutY="460.0" preserveRatio="true" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="40.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="30.0">
         <viewport>
            <Rectangle2D />
         </viewport>
         <image>
            <Image url="@themes/theme0/wsit.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <Label layoutX="55.0" layoutY="430.0" text="Developed by" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="65.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="30.0">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="10.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Hyperlink layoutX="66.0" layoutY="545.0" text="workspaceit.com" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="30.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="27.0">
         <font>
            <Font size="10.0" />
         </font>
      </Hyperlink>
      <MenuBar fx:id="menuBar" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <menus>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="APP">
               <items>
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Reset Password" />
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
               </items>
            </Menu>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="HELP">
               <items>
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Check for Updates" />
               </items>
            </Menu>
         </menus>
      </MenuBar>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Can anyone suggest me whats i am doing wrong??

Comment: Well determine that property by partially deleting nodes from fxml file and re-running it.

Comment: Looks fine for me...

Comment: @UlukBiy how to do that??!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i fixed it by uninstalling the current version of JavaFX Scene Builder 1.1 and installed JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0 . So may be i had some compatibility issue.
So [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafxscenebuilder-1x-archive-2199384.html) is the download link.